# Adding Attribute to property in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add an attribute to a property in VB.NET, so I can then check that attribute later
I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way. Some pointers on how to do this and also then how to check that attribute at run time would be great.

```
Public Class Person

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is forename property 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <ExcludeFromModifiedComparision(True)>
    Public Property Forename = "Mickey"

    <ExcludeFromModifiedComparision(False)>
    Public Property Surname = "Mouse"
End Class

Public Class ExcludeFromModifiedComparisionAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As Boolean)
        ' Not sure what to do here?
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly with the ExcludeFromModifiedComparisionAttribute Class? Because I understand that you are writing this in VB.NET winforms, isn't it?

Comment: I want to add those attributes to my person class so some other code can see if they are true or false and apply logic accordingly. I'm just not getting my head around how to do it at all.

Comment: I never use attributes; that's why I asked you about what you were exactly after, to understand the exact point here. Attributes provide further information for the given property and I was expecting to assign this further information statically (True or False inside the <> part), not via initialising another class. Although I cannot be sure if what you intend can be done or not (not too much experience on this matter); in any case, I don't get the point: why you want the Sub New to be triggered?

Comment: The corresponding MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx) comes from an approach similar to yours. But the point of the Sub New is assigning different values. If you want to assign just one value (true or false) why passing it as argument to a different class? In any case, you should modify your class such that the value (true/false) is actually stored (just emulate the example in MSDN). All the triggering part (error or any other thing... from the debugger), I am not too sure how will behave here as far as you aren't performing a "standard variable assignation".

Comment: That article seems to be adding attributes to the class rather than the property?

Comment: Yes. But shows how to interact with Attributes defined by an external class as you are doing. You need to look at the way the Sub New store the input values (you have to create a variable inside the Class, otherwise no information will be stored).

Comment: Ah ok, I can do that no problem and it will just work the same with properties? Thanks

Comment: It seems like this will be case. But, as said, not too experienced in all this. I asked you just to find out the exact reason for relying on such an approach (you cannot get Attributes as immediately as, for example, other properties). If you wait a bit, most likely, will come here a more-experienced-than-me-on-this person and will solve your doubts.